# Setting up CMake with gfortran in Windows to run CACTUS

Tags: windows, cmake, gfortran, lapack, blas

My ultimate goal is to run [CACTUS](https://github.com/SNL-WaterPower/CACTUS). It requires CMake, so I have downloaded both. I think CMake needs a compiler, so I downloaded MinGW (or gfortran or GNU, I'm not really sure the distinction).

Using the MinGW Installation Manager, I've installed `mingw32-base`, `mingw32-gcc-fortran`, and also all the MinGW libraries because at one point I thought it would help. I have navigated through

```
control panel>system>advanced system settings>advanced>environment
```

variables and in user variables I have added the variables CMake and FC with the values `C:\ProgramFiles\CMake\bin` and `C:\MinGW\bin`, respectively.

I also edited the path in system variables to include both of those as well as `C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin`. I've also downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 because I read somewhere that it was necessary for gfortran to work, though I have not done anything directly with it so far. At this point, I open Windows command prompt (this is all in Windows 10), navigate to the build folder that I have created in the top CACTUS folder and type

```
cmake ../
```

It returns this:

```
-- Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
-- LAPACK requires BLAS
-- A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_Fortran (missing: OpenMP_Fortran_FLAGS OpenMP_Fortran_LIB_NAMES)
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:272 (message):
    The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (OpenMP)   
    does not match the name of the calling package (OPENMP). This can lead to
    problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables   
    (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:579 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_Fortran_FOUND)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:32 (message):
  OPENMP option was set to true (default), but no OpenMP was found. Install   
  OpenMP, or try again with -DOPENMP=OFF.  Exiting.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Starting at the top of that error, I did some googling and found these [instructions](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#lapacke) starting at "Build Instructions to create LAPACK and LAPACKE 3.5.0 dlls for Windows with MinGW". I followed those instructions for Win32. After running `C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe` from command prompt, it gets to 36% and errs with the following message:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lFALSE
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
SRC\CMakeFiles\lapack.dir\build.make:28574: recipe for target 'bin/liblapack.dll' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [bin/liblapack.dll] Error 1 
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2077: recipe for target 'SRC/CMakeFiles/lapack.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [SRC/CMakeFiles/lapack.dir/all] Error 2 
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have also tried directions [here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/index.html#libraries) and [here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/index.html#running) and have either had no luck or, frankly, don't understand them. I am not a programmer. I have lived a life spoiled by GUIs and single install programs with everything included. I don't know what to try anymore. I don't really understand what's wrong or, honestly, why I've taken most of the steps I've taken except that someone in another help forum suggested them. I guarantee that I will have follow up questions to your answers, but please help.

**EDIT**

As requested below, here is the config file for lapack after cmake:

```
# Load the LAPACK package with which we were built.
set(LAPACK_DIR "C:/Users/x/Downloads/lapack/lapack-3.9.0/build")
find_package(LAPACK NO_MODULE)

# Load lapack targets from the build tree, including lapacke targets.
if(NOT TARGET lapacke)
  include("C:/Users/x/Downloads/lapack/lapack-3.9.0/build/lapack-targets.cmake")
endif()

# Hint for project building against lapack
set(LAPACKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID ${LAPACK_Fortran_COMPILER_ID})

# Report lapacke header search locations from build tree.
set(LAPACKE_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/Users/x/Downloads/lapack/lapack-3.9.0/build/include")

# Report lapacke libraries.
set(LAPACKE_LIBRARIES lapacke ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
```

And, yes, I did choose to build the LAPACKE Library in CMake.

Comment: Please, do NOT format error logs as *blockuote*: this formatting doesn't preserve newlines and resulted logs become harder to understand. For logs use **code formatting** instead.

Comment: The error message `cannot find -lFALSE` smells like you have assigned `FALSE` value to some variable which is intended to contain a library path.

Comment: Sorry about the block quote. I have intentionally assigned anything to 'FALSE'. If that's the case, what do I do?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, I have NOT assigned anything to `FALSE` that I know of. What do I do to sort this out?

Comment: Try to search `FALSE` in `CMakeCache.txt` file which is located in the *build directory*.

Comment: BTW, your *specific* problem is building LAPACK (as far as I understand from the question). Why do you describe building CACTUS, which is definitely irrelevant to the problem, and provide details more that for LAPACK itself?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I barely know what I'm doing, so I provided as much detail as I could since I'm not sure what the problem is. You're right that it seems like the most immediate issue is building LAPACK, but I wasn't even certain that that was necessary. I'm also doubtful that it will be the last issue I have. Regarding the search for `FALSE` in `CMakeCache.txt`, I found two instances: `//Dependencies for the target
lapack_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;FALSE;` and `//Dependencies for the target
tmglib_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;lapack;general;FALSE;` I don't know what to do with this information now.

Comment: "I barely know what I'm doing, so I provided as much detail as I could since I'm not sure what the problem is." - Your problem is installing LAPACKE. Everything else is secondary. Please, show (add to the question post) the **configuration log** of LAPACKE (the one you get after `cmake`). "I followed those instructions for Win32." - The instructions you refer to contains branches not only for 32 vs 64 bit. E.g. it has a line `if you want to build the LAPACKE library, set the 'LAPACKE' option to ON.`. Have you followed that suggestion?